# XQuery Error: XPTY0019: Required item type of first operand of '/' is node();

Tags: xml, xquery

I want to grab some data from xml by xquery. The original xml is something like:

```
<mondial>
<country id="AAA" name="BBB" gdp_total="XXX" population_growth="XXX">
<name>BBB</name>
<city id="CCC" country="AAA">
<name>DDD</name>
<population>XXXX</population>
<located_at type="XX"/>
</city>
...
</country>
...
</mondial>
```

I write a XQuery like that:

```
declare function local:globals_1(){
let $countries:=("mondial-3.0.xml")//country[@gdp_total > number(100000) and @population_growth > number(0.3)]
let $cities:=("mondial-3.0.xml")//city
for $country in $countries
for $city in $cities
where $country/@id = $city/@country 
order by number($city/@population)
return $city
};
<globals>
{local:globals_1()}
</globals>
```

An error came up:

> F [Saxon-PE XQuery 9.6.0.7] XPTY0019: Required item type of first
>   operand of '/' is node(); supplied value has item type xs:string

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`("mondial-3.0.xml")` is just a sequence of string containing single item. It is not a kind of `node()`, hence the error. I believe you want to call `doc()` function instead to read data from file :

```
let $countries := doc("mondial-3.0.xml")//......
let $cities := doc("mondial-3.0.xml")//city
......
```

Comment: @Mayoco you are welcome! don't forget to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer once you have chance to do so. Thanks